# CodeIgniter controller always calling index function

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, php-5.5

Whenever I try to add a new controller and access various public functions through URL, than only redirecting to index() function and not accessing function according to the URL request

Example Code is

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class courses extends CI_Controller
{    
    public function __construct()    
    {    
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        define('CurrPage', 'Courses');
    }    
    public function index()
    {
        echo "is in Index";    
    }    
    public function categoryInfo()
    {
        echo "is in cat";    
    }

    public function c()
    {
        echo "is in c";    
    }  
}
```

test is the controller 
when type URL "..../test/"

Output is

> is in Index

when type URL "..../test/c/"

Output is

> is in Index

when type URL "..../test/categoryInfo/"

Output is

> is in Index

Code in config/routes.php

```
  $route['default_controller'] = "home";
  $route['404_override'] = 'courses';  
  $route['v/(:any)']= "video_single/index"; 
  $route['userInfo/(:any)']= "userInfo/index";
```

Comment: what is written at your `config/routes.php`

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = 'courses';
$route['v/(:any)']= "video_single/index";
$route['userInfo/(:any)']= "userInfo/index";

Comment: delete all and use this `$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';` and try.

Comment: Show the code of application/config/routes.pho

Comment: added routes code please check

Comment: @ShaifulIslam tried same result

Comment: same should not be happened.Did you set `$route['404_override'] = '';`?

Comment: this will only be considered if i entered wrong controller and i am entering right controller ...also am able to access the controller but not it's functions

Comment: you did not realized what I wanted to tell.What output you got when you set `$route['404_override'] = '';` I am 100% sure you getting 404 errors when your url is `.../test/c/`

Comment: already tested that and if any error in url `../test/c/` it will redirect to `../courses/` but it is showing `is in Index` i have also removed and tested...that's not the case

Comment: `$go = $this->uri->segment(2);
  if($go==""){
  $data['categories'] = $this->user_model->hobbyallCategories();
  $this->load->view('templates/head');
  $this->load->view('templates/header');
  $this->load->view('crshobby',$data);
  $this->load->view('templates/footer',$data);
  }elseif($go=="c"){
   
   $this->c();
   }` i don't know why i have to call all functions like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this to config/routes.php

```
$controllers = array('test' );
foreach($controllers as $controller) {
    $route[$controller] = $controller."/index";
    $route[$controller."/(:any)"] = $controller."/$1";
}
```